# Issue with Xamarin Firebase Subscribe to a Child with no Key - Newtonsoft.Json error

Tags: xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, json.net

I have a Firebase Child called "Parameters" that stores some data while my program runs. I populate it with "Put" and "Patch" actions. I cannot get the subscribe to work... I'm stuck on this Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException and I've tried several things but cannot figure it out. You can see in the error, I am getting the payload back... I just cannot parse it into my ViewParameterModel property variables. I would appreciate any help to get this working. Thanks, Brian

$exception {Firebase.Database.FirebaseException: Exception occured while processing the request.
Request Data: Response: {"aug":true,"fan":true,"ign":false,"mode":"Off","target":200}
---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value True to type 'Chart_sample.ViewParameterModel'. Path 'aug', line 1, position 11.
---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.Boolean to Chart_sample.ViewParameterModel.

**FirebaseHelper.cs**

```
...
private readonly string ChildParams = "ControllerData/Pellet_Pirate_1/Parameters";

        public ObservableCollection<Parameter> GetParameters()
        {
            firebase.Child(ChildParams).AsObservable<ViewParameterModel>().Subscribe(snapp =>
            {
                ViewParameterModel.aug = snapp.Object.aug;
                ViewParameterModel.fan = snapp.Object.fan;
                ViewParameterModel.ign = snapp.Object.ign;
                ViewParameterModel.mode = snapp.Object.mode;
                ViewParameterModel.target = snapp.Object.target;
            });
            return null;
        }
...
```

**ViewParameterModel.cs**

```
    public class ViewParameterModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private bool Fan = false;
        public bool fan
        {
            get
            {
                return Fan;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Fan != value)
                {
                    Fan = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("fan"));
                }
            }
        }

        private bool Igniter = false;
        public bool ign
        {
            get
            {
                return Igniter;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Igniter != value)
                {
                    Igniter = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ign"));
                }
            }
        }

        private bool Auger = false;
        public bool aug
        {
            get
            {
                return Auger;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Auger != value)
                {
                    Auger = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("aug"));
                }
            }
        }

        private string Mode = "Off";
        public string mode
        {
            get
            {
                return Mode;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Mode != value)
                {
                    Mode = value;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Mode: " + Mode);
                    if (SegmentBindingContext != null)
                    {
                        SegmentBindingContext.index = Mode.Equals("Off") ? 0 : Mode.Equals("Start") ? 1 : Mode.Equals("Smoke") ? 2 :
                                                    Mode.Equals("Hold") ? 3 : Mode.Equals("Ignite") ? 4 : 5;
                    }
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("mode"));
                }
            }
        }

        private int Target = 0;
        public int target
        {
            get
            {
                return Target;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Target != value)
                {
                    Target = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("target"));
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You do not instantiated`ViewParameterModel`, please instantiate it, then used in the `Subscribe()` method. `var myViewParameterModel = new ViewParameterModel()`, then `firebase.Child(ChildParams).AsObservable<ViewParameterModel>().Subscribe(snapp =>
            {
                myViewParameterModel.aug = snapp.Object.aug;
                myViewParameterModel.fan = snapp.Object.fan;
                myViewParameterModel.ign = snapp.Object.ign;
                myViewParameterModel.mode = snapp.Object.mode;
                myViewParameterModel.target = snapp.Object.target;  });`

Comment: Can you share a demo about this issue?

Comment: Please delete the above comment, your personal information will be disclosed(You shared account info), I notfice your demo that used `Syncfusion`, it is a third-part plugin, you can open a thread in `Syncfusion` forum. https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/xamarin.forms?_ga=2.51921952.880615750.1590568046-876399018.1550198972

Comment: it's all bogus account info and test accounts, not my production site.  Is there a better approach to provide a Xamarin "demo" for this issue?